# TypeError: image.elevateZoom is not a function: Failure in Magento 1.9 RWD theme

Tags: error, javascript, magento-1.9

in Magento 1.9 CE, if we browse the product reviews page, it displays an error

```
TypeError: image.elevateZoom is not a function
```

This is becuase, magento is using image zoom in product page using this [plugin](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples)

the JavaScript interpreter because of a failure shuts down on this page, JavaScript is not executed. This leads to decreased functionality of the page
Does anyone can help me on how to remove this error so that i can us js on this page???
[These](http://magento-forum.ru/topic/4430/) guys says, they have solved the problem, but i can't get the solution.

Comment: file path is
design/frontend/rwd/default/template/review/product/view/list.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the same issue - not that it's a complete solution but it certainly stops the error for now, by stopping the function being called on the review page.

in the file /skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js

line 649 change

```
image.elevateZoom();
```

to

```
if ($j('.review-product-list').length == 0) {
image.elevateZoom();
}
```